# Audioplayer plugins using a deprecated version of the android embedding

Tags: flutter

I want to add Audioplayer package for my xylophone app but on running it, I get this following error:

> The plugins `audioplayers, path_provider` use a deprecated version of
> the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future
> build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2
> embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of
> Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author,
> take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
> https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: Are you using the latest version?

Comment: the latest version of what?

Comment: Of the audioplayer plugin

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem while using audioplayers library. So, after looking up on the internet I found out that I was using the old version of the dependency of audio player. So, I suggest you to check for the latest version of audioplayers library from https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers, and add it in your dependency as

dependencies:
audioplayers: ^0.20.1

(For me it was 0.20.1). You can check for latest to avoid error. Hope it works for you.